# Creating a bootstrapper in ASP.NET MVC 3 using Ninject and DependencyResolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-2

I am attempting to create a simple bootstrapper. My boostrapper code looks like:

```
public static void Run()
{
    var tasks = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IBootstrapperTask>();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.Execute();
    }
}
```

The IBootstrapperTask interface looks like:

```
public interface IBootstrapperTask
{
    void Execute();
}
```

My first attempt to was to register routes through the bootstrapper:

```
public class RegisterRoutes : IBootstrapperTask
{
    private readonly RouteCollection routes;

    public RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    public RegisterRoutes() : this(RouteTable.Routes)
    {
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

My global.asax looks like:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    Bootstrapper.Run();
}
```

And my NinjectDependencyResolver looks like:

```
kernel.Bind<IBootstrapperTask>().To<RegisterRoutes>();
```

However, when I try to run this code I get the following exception:

> Error activating VirtualPathProvider
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>
> Activation path:
>
> 3) Injection of dependency VirtualPathProvider into parameter virtualPathProvider of constructor of type RouteCollection
>
> 2) Injection of dependency RouteCollection into parameter routes of constructor of type RegisterRoutes
>
> 1) Request for IBootstrapperTask

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The missing binding that was required for my example to work was:

```
kernel.Bind<RouteCollection>().ToConstant(RouteTable.Routes);
```

This binding will not be required if you use the Ninject MVC extension since it already has this binding and a few others out of the box as per the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application about how to use `Ninject.Extensions.MVC` correctly. It will add the necessary bindings.

Comment: Remo, can you explain why using the extension will solve my problem? Is it because certain bindings have already been established for me (like VirtualPathProvider in this case)? More importantly, if I choose not to go with the extension, what kind of binding would solve my issue above? Thanks for you help.

Comment: It adds the nesessary bindings. 

Sorry for not analyzing what you have to add to fix your own implementation. I simply don't have to time to support all the custom implementations. Supporting one implementation already takes a lot of time. And I don't see a point in going with a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about exactly Ninject, but encountered the same issue with other containers.

Looks like container takes the constructor with parameter by default, tries to use auto-wiring but doesn't know what to inject in place of `RouteCollection`.

I would try to either:

- Tweak container registration to use the exact constructor you need (e.g. using lambda, I'm pretty sure Ninject should allow for registrations like `kernel.Bind<IBootstrapperTask>().To(() => new RegisterRoutes());` or
- (probably the better way) Register something as `RouteCollection`. Id est - `kernel.Bind<RouteCollection>().To(RouteTable.Routes)`. **Update:** as Remo is saying there is MVC Extensions for Ninject where such registration is already provided out of the box (and probaly most of the others you'll need). So, definitely go this way. Using those extension for convenience is a good idea.

Comment: Ninject.Extensions.MVC already has Bind<RouteCollection>().ToConstant(RouteTable.Routes) by default. Adding another one will result in an exception

Comment: Maybe, but there is nothing about extensions in the topic (I didn't know about them as well, I'm mostly a StructureMap user). And the exception mentioned in the topic is **exactly** the exception when IoC container tries to resolve RouteCollection for given BootstrapperTask. It tries to create an instance of RouteCollection class but fails on finding the VirtualPathProvider for its constructor (which means that `RouteTable.Routes` isn't registered as default `RouteCollection`). Seems like topic starter doesn't use such an extension. I'll update my answer a bit to state that clearly.